# Command Line Works - .Bat Script Doesn't

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When attempting to run the following commands via the cmd prompt on a windows 2008 server everything works successfully. However once those same commands are saved to a .bat or .cmd file the script no longer works.

```
@echo off
set FILE="\\servername\c$\users\users\desktop\test.txt"
FOR %I in (%FILE%) DO set SIZE=%~ZI
IF %SIZE% == 75 (
copy "\\servername\c$\users\users\desktop\test.txt" "\\servername\c$\users\users\desktop\test-1.txt"
del "\\servername\c$\users\users\desktop\test.txt"
) ELSE (
echo "Failure"
)

TIMEOUT /T -1
```

I'm not sure what the difference would be and would appreciate any help that can be provided. The text file I'm using has the following text in it.

"
hello goodmorning
I need this to have a file size.

this file size is 75

"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside batch scripts, variables for `for` loops need two `%` symbols.

`FOR %%I in (%FILE%) DO set SIZE=%%~ZI`

Comment: Thank you very much - That resolved the issue.
After the 10 minute window I'll "accept" your answer.